# For window user authentication, have a window API that authenticates the user using a kerberos ticket?

Tags: kerberos

1. For window user authentication, have a window API that authenticates the user using a kerberos ticket? If any the API, I would like to know how to sign in to windows without a password.
2. Have a easy way to issue a Keberos a ticket! (Ex: window API)

Can anyone give me advice,

Thanks & best regards

Comment: This question is unclear and doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. Kerberos is the primary method of authenticating users on Windows for interactive logons using passwords/certificates and network logons using Kerberos tickets. Do you mean you want to get a Kerberos ticket for that user and log the user into a Windows interactive/remote session? Short answer is no, you need to primary credential for things like DPAPI and SSO to work correctly.

Comment: Hi steve, 
I have revised the question to make it easier to clear, can you give me any advice.

Comment: You can't sign into Windows interactively with just a Kerberos ticket. You must provide a credential (password, certificate, FIDO, etc.). The API's you're looking for are in the SSPI set: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/initializesecuritycontext--kerberos

Comment: Steve, Thank you very much!

Comment: @Steve About Credential Providers in Windows: Password, certificate, Fido. 
In case I don't want to use Password, I want to use Certificate, Fido to authenticate user window, and I want to know if there is a way to create a kerberos ticket by using Certificate, Fido? I have also searched microsoft's win32 API libraries but the results were not as expected. Seemingly does not support. Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You pass a handle of the certificate to the AcquireCredentialsHandle call. There is no way to request a Kerberos ticket using a FIDO credential from SSPI. You must use the logged in credential for that.

Comment: @Steve, Thanks for the suggestion, explaining about the mechanism Certifications, Fido. Also if possible I really want to know is there is any simple method to issues (create) kerberos tickets?

Comment: The ACH and ISC functions within SSPI are the easiest you will find in the Win32 API.